# Does it really happen that an 3D object imported into Assimp has multiple meshes?

Tags: mesh, collada, fbx, assimp

In Assimp API `aiNode` can be linked with multiple meshes.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; ++i)
    {
        auto j = node->mMeshes[i];
        aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[j];
    }
```

I unsuccessfully tried to create such file (FBX/OBJ/DAE) for testing purposes.
Can you please provide example of such file where some object linked with multiple meshes.
Is it ever possible for FBX/OBJ/DAE or this feature implemented for other 3D formats?
For example in Blender there no possibility (as far as I know) to put multiple meshes into one object.

[Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBc7h.png)

Comment: `mMeshes` - hold indexes of `aiMesh` from `aiScene`. In `aiMesh` documentation (
http://sir-kimmi.de/assimp/lib_html/structai_mesh.html)
you can read that:
_"A mesh represents a geometry or model with a **single material**."_

Maybe if you add in blender two materials to object, you get more meshes in assimp.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use our test data, this file could be interesting for you I guess [Testmodel](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/test/models/FBX/huesitos.fbx).

In Assimp we are using multiple meshes to manage different materials and animations. At this moment each mesh has one material assigned. Other topics are skeletal-based animations: we are modeling the skeleton via instances of scene-nodes. And each node has a dedicated mesh assigned to it.